# Excel custom combination chart randomly stops displaying data series

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have a peculiar problem that comes and goes somewhat randomly. I am creating a chart using VBA. I first add up to 10 data series on an XY chart  and then I add one more data series as a clustered column. The code works as it should and the graph is created and all of the data is there.

The problem comes in when I try to update the chart to plot a different set of data. It will usually work correctly once or twice but then the data will just stop showing up on the chart but the labels and legend will still be there. The data still exists in the chart and I can get it to appear again by going to the Excel Select Data menu and selecting one of the data series or by restarting the program, but until I do one of those things its just an empty chart.

The code I use to update the plot is included below. It simply checks a few cells to see what data to actually plot then grabs that data and adds it to the chart. I have stepped through it line-by-line but never got the problem to occur this way.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim rn, rn2, colorRn As Range
Dim i, j, MyLength, numlines, MyEnd As Integer
Dim MyAdd, MyChar As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Data")
Set cht = ws.ChartObjects("Data_Chart")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Find Last row to use in plots, this is due to combo plot limitation
    Set rn = ws.Range("D45:M45")
    Set rn2 = ws.Range("D43:M43")
    MyEnd = CInt(Right(ws.Range("B44").CurrentRegion.Address, 3))

'Clear Prev Plot Series
cht.Activate
numlines = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
If ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count > 0 Then
    i = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
    While i > 0
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Delete
    i = i - 1
    Wend
Else
End If

'Plot or not range
Set rn = ws.Range("B5:G14")

'Add data series
For i = 1 To rn.Rows.Count
    If rn(i, 4) = "Yes" Then
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        numlines = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
        With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(numlines)
            .Name = ws.Range("B" & CStr(i + 4))
            .XValues = ws.Range("B45:B" & MyEnd)
            .Values = ws.Range(rn(i, 6) & "45:" & rn(i, 6) & MyEnd)

        'format color
            .MarkerForegroundColor = rn(i, 5).Cells.Interior.Color
            .MarkerBackgroundColor = rn(i, 5).Cells.Interior.Color
            .MarkerSize = 3
        End With
    Else
    End If
Next i

'********* Try to insert columns
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
numlines = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(numlines)
    .Name = ws.Range("C44")
    .XValues = ws.Range("B45:B" & MyEnd)
    .Values = ws.Range("A45:A" & MyEnd)
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    'Format column color
    .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
End With
ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 0
'Fix scale for combo plot
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelSpacing = 10
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorTickMark = xlOutside
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryGridLinesNone)

Call MyRescalePos

Set rn = Nothing
Set cht = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

And the Rescale sub

```
Sub MyRescalePos()

Worksheets("Data").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Data_Chart").Activate


    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Worksheets("Data").Range("Q8")
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Worksheets("Data").Range("Q9")
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = Worksheets("Data").Range("Q10")
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0

End Sub
```

I can't see anything wrong except that maybe Excel just doesn't like combo plots. I also haven't been able to find any other posts online relating to a similar issue where the data seems to be formatted correctly and actually exists in the chart, just isn't displayed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you manually investigate the chart settings to see if there is something in your code that is causing unintended settings?

Comment: As far as I have been able to see, the chart settings don't change between the data being displayed and not being displayed. As I mentioned, it is as simple as opening the Select Data menu and just clicking one of the data series, I don't even edit it. I just click on a data series in that menu and the data instantly appears.